# How to get the last record using Eloquent scope?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, octobercms

I have a `Posts` table structured like this:

[image]

Now I'm trying to get the latest post which is obviously the record with `id = 2`.

I have this in my theme page `posts.htm`:

```
[builderList postLatest]
modelClass = "Me\Articles\Models\Posts"
scope = "scopeLatest"
scopeValue = "{{ :scope }}"
displayColumn = "title"
noRecordsMessage = "No records found"
detailsPage = "-"
detailsUrlParameter = "slug"
pageNumber = "{{ :page }}"
```

in my model `Posts` I have:

```
public function scopeLatest($query)
{
  return $query->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
}
```

But this one is returning **both records**. I also tried using `latest()`

`return $query->latest();`

And this one gives me the error:

```
Maximum function nesting level of '1000' reached, aborting!
```

Even tried passing parameter like `latest('created_at')` but got the same error.

Tried dumping `dd($query->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first()->toSql())` and got **`select * from posts where posts.deleted_at is null`**

1. Why `first()` is not limiting to 1 record?
2. Why `latest()` is throwing me `Maximum error`? Is this version specific bug? It seems I cant find documentation related to it. I have Laravel 5.5.48.

I'm not sure now what can I use. Maybe I'm doing something wrong here. I just need to get the latest post.

Comment: hi @kerbholz I'm getting the error `Maximum function..`. This is what bugs me the most. I don't understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Is `latest()` not compatible with OctoberCMS?

Comment: afaik `first()` closes the query, it does a `LIMIT 1` and then takes the first result of that query. Check the source code.

Comment: it is not correct to use the `first()`  inside the scopes because they are meant to be chained (i.e. adding another behaviour to query) so i guess its good. instead you can add static method inside modal and return single latest record `self::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();` and use component to show that i guess

Comment: you might have a pointer a point there that scopes are meant to be chained maybe that is why `first()` is not working? But not sure how I would apply chaining using the `builderList` format, since I can't find it in the documentation. I did try using too `self::orderBy('created_at','desc')->first()` but still getting two records. Maybe I'm overlooking something in the record? No. OctoberCMS seems has not so much detail documentation.

Comment: can you share code how you are using `self::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();` and share dump of its result. may be we can figure out why its returning 2 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is using the `->take(1)` [method](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/collections#method-take). There are more methods applicable to queries but here is the list of [available methods](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/collections#available-methods) you can run on a collection instance. I believe Builder expects scopes to return a query `{[a collection of models]}`. I took some time to do testing and in my opinion this might just be a flaw in the Builder Plugin construction.

Now before you look at my research below. I would say you should learn to build your own [components](https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components) like Hardik suggests in a comment. Hope this all helps.

So here is a scope I have for a plugin:

```
public function scopeFilterTypes($query) {
    return $query->whereNotIn('slug', [
        'range', 
        'close',
        'all', 
        'single',
        'three',
        'five',
        'self'
        ])->first();
}
```

Here is a picture of my backend form which correctly only sees one item in the relationship (this is why I am using a scope):

[image]

Now look at this image of my builder component You can see that it even ignores my `->whereNotIn([])` method on the query:

[image]

To prove my finding on this flaw in the builder component I do a `find($id)` method which would return a model instance not a collection of models. Using the `find($id)` method also gives me the correct result in the backend form but in the Builder list shows me all the records which is incorrect.

**However when I change the scope to `->take(1)`:**

```
public function scopeFilterTypes($query) {
    return $query->whereNotIn('slug', [
        'range', 
        'close',
        'all', 
        'single',
        'three',
        'five',
        'self'
        ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(1);
}
```

I get this in the backend form; working correctly:
[image]

And I get this from the builder list:

[image]

Comment: Actually I managed to get it, with `->take(1)`. I just forgot to return to this thread. Anyway, Thank you for the other explanations too. I've got too many questions running in my brain right now about OctoberCMS. haha, I'm feeling it made the Laravel more complicated or it is just a learning curve.